# Can't install Intel HAXM - no error meesage no setup screen

Tags: android, windows, intel, haxm

I am trying to install HAXM for my Android studio, after I downloaded the installer from the [official site](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/) and tried to run it, a extracting dialog flashed up and disappeared immdiately. [image]

Then I can see the installer in my task manager, but nothing pops up, not even the setup screen that's supposed to show up.[image]

This is what's supposed to show up:[image]

After a while, the installer entry in my task manager just disappear by itself.

I tried to run it on my friend's laptop and it worked properly.
I tried to download the installer from the Android sdk manager, and it doesn't work as well.
I tried to run the haxm_check.exe and both categories said yes.

[image]

Ive also checked that the Virtualization Technology (vt-x) option is enabled in the UEFI settings.

My laptop is running on windows 8, and it has a i7-3630qm processor, and [this](http://ark.intel.com/products/71459/Intel-Core-i7-3630QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz?q=i7%203630qm) website shows that it matches all the system requirements specified [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows)

I have read many posts regarding HAXM installation fails but none of them match my situation. Any idea why it failed in my case? Any help will be much appreciated!

UPDATE:

1. I downloaded an older version of HAXM(1.0.8 instead of 6.0.3), and it installed properly (but I still need the latest version to launch the emulator), hmmmm...... I wonder what the problem is.
2. I've tried 6.0.1 as well, same problem as 6.0.3.
3. I tried updating my system to 8.1 (what my friend had on his computer, the one that I tried installing and worked), still no luck D;

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution:
right click on "intelhaxm-android.exe" and select "extract here", then run "setup.exe"

EDIT:
I found this solution on the Internet from someone else's answer, but it does not say why this would work. I am assuming that the extration phase somehow keeps failing so the installation keeps failing as well, and manually extracting the setup.exe makes it work. Am I right?

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. Can't seem to find any other answers to this question either.